# Mix It Up plugin not working with bootstrap tab structure

Tags: jquery

I am using a plugin which is not working properly. For example

[Link](http://hf-dev.com/customdirectory/MixitUp/index.php)

Click on the Open Tabs link on this page you will see a bootstrap modal pop up which has a few tabs in it with mixitup plugin.

Initially it shows a long list of elements which shows because it does not work properly. Resize your window by opening up console or using browser resize button you will notice that the grids arrange themselves properly.

How can I solve this issue?? I am trying to call window resize function but that does not work. Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed a simple thing there.. You are calling the window resize function and as far as I am concerned, it will work using the window resize function only. But use the window resize in a slight different way and that is

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(window).resize();
}, 100);
```

This should do the trick.. Cheers...